# Akeneo 2.1.4 : How can I change an attribute type?

Tags: attributes, pim, akeneo

I have an attribute of type `pim_catalog_number`, but I need to change this to `pim_catalog_simpleselect`. I cannot change this in Akeneo and if I try to overwrite it by importing a new attributes-file I get the notice that I am not allowed to change the type.

But I have a scenario where I need to do this. So what's the proper way to do this? I can imagine doing some direct SQL queries, but what are the consequences of changing the type directly in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now the only solution is to export the product values, delete the attribute, create the attribute with the right type and then re-import the products.

We are currently working on a proper solution to do that, but with all the feature of the PIM involved (history, rules, proposals, search, etc) it's not an easy task. We dedicate 1 dev full time on this task for the next three months to come up with a nice solution.